# Android listview notifyDataSetChanged() jumpes to bottom

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

every time when I call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter the listview displayes the last item in the adapter array. 
Is there any possible way to scroll the listview to the top off screen, since the setSelection(n) method within the post runnable is noticable, because the listview jumps to the bottom and then to the top. This movement can be seen on the screen unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, you're telling the ListView to refresh its contents, and it will actually try not to scroll if possible. It knows what it's currently scrolled to based on the items' positions and ids that it has obtained from the adapter. Your issue may be that your adapter is giving out inconsistent ids from `getItemId` that are confusing the ListView, causing it to scroll unnecessarily. Can you explain a little more about what your code is doing at the time you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Are you adding or removing items in the adapter at the same time?

Comment: basically ive 2 arraylists. the first one gets updated and new items are added to the top. This listview is then cloned and modified because some items have to be inserted in between. This updated list is then passed to the adapter and the notifiy is called

Comment: Yep, if you add items to the top, it will try to stay at wherever it was before they were added, which is probably the bottom. Try calling `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` before changing the data, or changing `getItemId` in your adapter to always return the position and `hasStableIds` to true.

Comment: oke found the problem had : .setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL); enbaled

Comment: ...haha, yep, that would do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
lv.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: dude smoothscroll is as visible as setSelection. the point is to get the listview instant without any movment up top